# Compute Powers and Put Them in the Form a+bi

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$$(-\sqrt3-i)^7$$

I'm not sure how to get the answer? The answer is:

$$(2^6)\sqrt3+(2^6)i$$

sorry about the formatting I'm still new

Comment: Convert the first number into its polar form. It is a known angle. Also your formatting was fine, you just had to add the \$$ on both sides and add a \ in front of the sqrts.

Comment: De Moivre's formula is what you're looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below,

$$(-\sqrt3-i)^7=\left[2\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-\frac12i\right)\right]^7$$
$$=2^7\left(\cos\frac{7\pi}{6}+\sin\frac{7\pi}{6}i\right)^7
=2^7(e^{i\frac{7\pi}{6}})^7=2^7e^{i\frac{49\pi}{6}}$$
$$=2^7\left(\cos\frac{49\pi}{6}+\sin\frac{49\pi}{6}i\right)=2^7\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+\sin\frac{\pi}{6}i\right)$$
$$=2^7\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\right)=2^6(\sqrt3+i)=2^6\sqrt3+2^6 i$$

Answer (score 0):

As  Ninad Munshi wrote,
to compute
$(a+bi)^n$,
first comvert
$a+bi$ to polar form.

To do this,
want
$a+bi
=re^{it}
$
where
$r \ge 0$ is real
and
$0 \le t \lt 2\pi$.

Then
$a+bi
=re^{it}
=r(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))
=r\cos(t)+ir\sin(t)
$
so
$a = r\cos(t),
b = r\sin(t)
$.

Then
$a^2+b^2
=r^2(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t))
=r^2
$
so
$r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$.

Then
$t$ is gotten by
$\tan(t)
=\dfrac{r\sin(t)}{r\cos(t)}
=\dfrac{b}{a}
$
and adjusting the quadrant
that $t$ is in
depending on
the signs of $a$ and $b$.

Finally,
if
$a+bi = re^{it}$,
$(a+bi)^n = (re^{it})^n
=r^ne^{int}
=r(\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)
$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the binomial theorem.
This is usually harder than
the polar form version.

$\begin{array}\\
(a+ib)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^k (ib)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k} (ib)^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k} i^kb^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k} i^{2k}b^{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor } \binom{n}{2k-1}a^{n-2k+1} i^{2k-1}b^{2k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k} (-1)^{k}b^{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor } \binom{n}{2k-1}a^{n-2k+1} (-i)(-1)^{k}b^{2k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k} (-1)^{k}b^{2k}-i\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor } \binom{n}{2k-1}a^{n-2k+1} (-1)^{k}b^{2k-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this problem can be solved using polar coordinates and DeMoivre's formula, mainly because the angle turns out to be a nice fraction of $\pi$. But if you know how to multiply complex numbers, then at the very least you can simply compute a seventh power step by step:

$$\begin{align}
x=-\sqrt3-i
&\implies x^2=(-\sqrt3-i)(-\sqrt3-i)=2+2\sqrt3 i\\
&\implies x^3=(-\sqrt3-i)(2+2\sqrt3i)=-8i\\
&\implies x^4=(-\sqrt3-i)(-8i)=-8+8\sqrt3i\\
&\implies\,\,etc.
\end{align}$$

But of course the nice result $x^3=-8i$ facilitates a short circuit:

$$x^7=x^3x^3x=(-8i)(-8i)(-\sqrt3-i)=-64(-\sqrt3-i)=64\sqrt3+64i$$

(Note, $64=2^6$) It's the nice result for $x^3$ that makes the DeMoivre approach work, and it can be worth spending some time thinking about why that is so. The take-home message is that, if you're asked to do a computation and you can't immediately think of an *easy* way to do it, just go ahead and start computing, and see what you learn along the way. Even if you wind up not learning anything, six multiplications aren't all that many to do, and at least you've got the answer -- and some useful practice in arithmetic.